# How to create instance of model during user registration process? Django

Tags: django

I am writing a simple event app in django. I have register and login process.

I have two models. Model creator has one `OneToOneField` with attribute `User`.

`Event` model has attribute `creator` as `ForeignKey` which contain specific `User`.

What is my problem? When I create new user, I want to create new instance of `Creator` model at the same time and when I log in as that user and create new event, I want to set value of creator in Event as this user.

How can I do it? `models.py` and `views.py` below:

`models.py`

```
class Event(models.Model):
    SPORT = (
        ('Football', 'Football'),
        ('Volleyball', 'Volleyball'),
        ('Basketball', 'Basketball'),
        ('Futsal', 'Futsal'),
        ('Tennis', 'Tennis'),
        ('Handball', 'Handball'),
        ('Ice Hockey', 'Ice Hockey'),
        ('Paintball', 'Paintball')
    )
    creator = models.ForeignKey(Creator, null=True,     on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    sport = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, choices=SPORT)
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    event_date = models.DateTimeField(default=date.today())
    end_event_date = models.DateTimeField(default=date.today())
    current_members = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    total_members = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    event_location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cost = models.FloatField(default=0, max_length=5)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.event_name

class Creator(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`views.py`

```
@unauthenticated_user
def registerPage(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Account created successfully!')
            return redirect('login')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'events/register.html', context)
```

Comment: Does the `Creator` model have any other fields?

Comment: I would not use the additional `Creator` model and just have the `creator` field in the `Event` as a foreign key to the `User` model. If you are not storing any additional information in the `Creator` model what purpose does it serve?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Creator does not have any other fields at the moment. I used User instead of Creator and it works!

Comment: Do you know how to set default value of field creator in Event as currently logged user? I do not want to set it manually every time I create event as a currently logged user.

Comment: @mateuszj - you can't set "current user" as a default on the model, but you can get the user from the `request` object as Ben described in their answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a new `Creator` at signup:

`views.py`

```py
...
from django.contrib.auth import User

from .models import Creator
...
    ...
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            Creator.objects.create(user=new_user)
            messages.success(request, 'Account created successfully!')
```

To add the creator to `Event`, you would `get()` the currently logged in user (`request.user`) from the `Creator` model, then pass that to the `creator` field when creating a new `Event`

Comment: Thanks, it also works, but I decided to not use Creator because it has only one field, so its useless.